# Eye brow & eye lashes not moving with rigify face rig

Tags: rigify

I created particle system on a face mesh for eyebrow & eyelashes. I rigged with rigify armature(full body including face rig).

Now all are ok but eyelashes not moving with eyelid. Same problem to eye brow also...

Any solution pls

Answer (score 2):

The particle system needs to know where the vertices are. For this to happen, the Armature modifier needs to do its job before the hair strands are added.

If your modifier stack looks like this
[image: Modifier stack in wrong order]
your hair strands will be added before the armature is put in play.
[image: Hair strands not following mesh deformation]
To remedy this, grab the dots inside the green box in the image, using your mouse and pull downwards, until the ParticleSystem modifier settles below the Armature modifier.

This is the appropriate order of the modifiers
[image: Correct order modifier stack]
And the result should be like this
[image: Hair strands following mesh deformation]

Comment: Thank you...I will try..